# Getting channel name and channel info from Twitch API

Tags: php, api, curl, twitch

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've been looking around for help in this subject all day and couldn't find anything very useful.

Here's what I'm trying to do: user goes to my website, logs in through Twitch, then when they're returned to my website I get their Twitch channel's name as well as some basic info about the channel (Views, subscribers, etc.)

As of now, I have the user log in through Twitch, and when they are returned to my website I am given a code as well as the scope and state that I set through GET. My problem is I'm not sure how to go about getting the channel name from this code, the documentation is just confusing me, and I wasn't able to find any tutorials online that explain this.

That being said, what do I have to do now to get the channel's name, given the code, scope, and state supplied to me by the Twitch API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have an Oauth token you can make a request to the `Users` api. You must send `Client-ID` and `Authorization` as headers.

More info here: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/users/#get-user

Comment: Appreciate the reply! I used a curl to PHP tool online to convert what's said in that documentation to this: http://pastebin.com/nRdYLUrG --executing that and then echoing out the data held in result gives me this, any idea why?:  stdClass Object
(  
    [error] => Unauthorized  
    [status] => 401  
    [message] => Cartman.GetAuthorizationToken: error getting authorization token  
)

Comment: Your oauth token is probably invalid or not sent

Comment: Figured that part out, I now have the token and the access token (the important one). I believe this is the last thing I need. If I try to use this access token in my web browser to get the channel's info it'll work fine, but when I try the same URL in my code (but replace the hardcoded token with the variable), PHP times out and I get a HTTP 500 error. I'm using cURL to send the request but I have the same issue if I try to use file_get_contents() as well. This should be my last questions, thanks for the help so far :) http://pastebin.com/WHw1GG9w

Comment: It seems like your issue is mostly with PHP. Unfortunately I have little experience with PHP.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks anyway. I'm still semi-new to PHP as well. Turns out json_decode returned an object rather than an array, and I since I was using array[key] instead of object->key, file_get_contents would simply timeout my PHP instead of showing the error. Again, thanks for all the help!